# How to Store values in specific column by using JSON from Postman (values are separated by underscore_)

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

Anybody please can help me it's easy to post data from Postman in below default JSON format `{"id":1, "firstName":"abc", "lastName":"xyz"}` by using `@RequestBody` Employee emp

but how to post data in this format `{"EMPLOYEE_DETAILS":"1_abc_xyz"}` And data will be stored in specific column

```
@Entity 
@Table(name="employee") 
public class Employee{
     @Id private int id;
     @Column(name = "first_name") 
     private String firstName;
     @Column(name = "last_name") 
     private String lastName;
     //Generate setters and getters 
}
```

Comment: It looks like a joke:D Anyway I would recommend to create sub class that converts you Entity to your weird template to post it and if it needs can convert it back to the entity. And when this bad design issue will be fixed just get rid of this class and start using you initial entity.

Answer (score 1):

You can take input in controller either `Map<String,String>` or create a `DTO` and then store value in String datatype like this

```
String data=map.get("EMPLOYEE_DETAILS");
or
String data=employeeDto.getEmployesDetails();
```

First split data by using _(underscore) like this

```
String splitter=data.split("_");
```

create all argument constructor in Employee enitity and pass by `splitter` like this

```
Employee employee =new Employee(splitter[0],splitter[1],splitter[2])
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi Anubhav, if I am going to use String data=employeeDto.getEmployesDetails(); how shall I get "EMPLOYEE_DETAILS"  and suppose ID is getting autogenerated from table itself how Constructor Injection will work here in Constructor Injection partial injection is not possible at all. Thank you.

Comment: Either you can make two argument constructor without id , and use  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
annotation for autogenerate value.

Comment: And how to get data in this JSON format {"EMPLOYEE_DETAILS":"abc_xyz"} details from employee table by using id.